# In isEmpty condition cakephp cacheing not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying cacheing query, condition is after first request and if query object is not empty I want to cache. I have tried like below

```
 public function getCategories()
 {   
        $categoriesTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get( 'Categories' );
    
        if(\Cake\Cache\Cache::read('categories', 'redis_cache') == null)
        {
            $categories = $categoriesTable->find();
    
            if(!$categories->isEmpty())
            {
                print("hello");
                $categories->cache('categories','redis_cache');
                debug(\Cake\Cache\Cache::read('categories', 'redis_cache'));
            }
            $this->set('categories',$categories);
        }else{
            $this->set('categories',\Cake\Cache\Cache::read('categories', 'redis_cache'));
        }
    
        $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize', ['categories']); 
}
```

Output I got in postman

1st time hit

```
hello
null
```

2nd time hit

```
hello
null
```

But after comment `if(!$categories->isEmpty())` condition

1st time hit

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 2,
...
}
```

Also if I write the condition like below it's also working fine.

```
if(!$categoriesTable->find('all')->isEmpty()). // it's working
```

What's the wrong I'm doing here ?

Comment: The issues with your code aside for a moment, why do you try to avoid caching empty results, usually that shouldn't really cause any problems?

Comment: Actually my plan was if cache empty , then check every time rather then wait for cache duration expired. Do you think it's better to give an empty check in cache read ?

Comment: What advantage do you expect to gain from doing that? I can tell you what's wrong with your code, but without knowing why exactly you want to do this empty check stuff, I might not be able to give you a proper solution. Note that you don't have to wait for the cache to expire, you're supposed to clear it once you update the cached source, for example when you insert/update/delete category records. And then you usually do not read the cache manually, but simply let the query handle that itself.

Comment: In backend I have a crawler script which will delete all data in a week and regenerate new data. I have a mobile app where I don't want to display user empty page until cache duration. Example my cache duration is 1 month. In my system after delete data backend it will regenerate in a minute.  Here I don't know when the delete script will run. So I don't want to take any risk. Actually the logic I want to apply if database is empty then try again until get data then set in cache.

Comment: @ndm Also I have curiosity to understand the concept of   isEmpty() check in this types of scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Queries are lazy evaluated**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-rows-from-a-table), meaning they are not being executed until the data is actually being requested, however `isEmpty()` is one of the methods that will cause the query to be executed, it needs the results to tell whether there are any.

Your code sets the query cacher config *afterwards*, which will have no effect, as further evaluation/iteration of the query object will not execute the query again (which is when it would normally cache its results), but access the runtime buffered results instead, hence no data is being cached.

If you need more control over how caching is being handled, then you maybe want to avoid the built-in query caching, and do it completely manually, eg read and also *write* the cache as neccessary.

As far as your use case is concerned, if you have a script running that deletes and regenerates the data, you might want to consider using it to also [**clear the cache**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands/cache.html) afterwards (`bin/cake cache clear redis_cache`). Then, if you implement the "*try again until there's data*" logic in the frontend, your backend code can be simplified to just read and cache whatever data there is, and if there is none yet, your frontend will let the user know that the data isn't ready yet and poll again. While websockets or server sent events might be better, long polling is certainly still preferable over having a script run minutes on end.